# Using AWS IOT to communicate between multiple IPad type devices

Tags: iot, aws-iot

I am looking at a project that is trying to connect a number of IPad type devices, so each can pass information to the other members of this group.

For example, given six devices, if Dev1 moves to a new position, that position information should be propagated to Dev2-6.  Similarly, if Dev2 moves, the information is passed to Dev1, Dev3-6.

It would seem to me that this might be doable by

1. Having a Message Broker with a MQTT topic to which all devices subscribe.
2. Writing the information to the broker
3. Then reading, or better still, pushing the data to other devices (perhaps using shadow devices).

Is this a reasonable approach?  (I don't quite see how to write to the message broker).

Could binary data be sent?

Any ideas on how it would scale?